Why does CachePut and CacheEvict not work in this example?
In my Java Spring MVC application I have a service that can do crud operations on customers. I use @Cacheable annotation on "loadCustomers" method that works fine but @CachePut annotation on "addOrEditCustomer" method and @CacheEvict annotation on "removeCustomer" method doesn't work. Is that correct? Why does CachePut and CacheEvict not work in this example?
@Service
public class CustomerService {

private final CustomerRepository _customerRepository;
private final ModelMapper _modelMapper;

public CustomerService(CustomerRepository customerRepository, ModelMapper modelMapper) {
    _customerRepository = customerRepository;
    _modelMapper = modelMapper;
}

@Cacheable("customers")
public List<CustomerDto> loadCustomers() {
    var customers = _customerRepository.findAllByOrderByIdDesc();
    var customerDtoList = new ArrayList<CustomerDto>();
    for (var customer : customers) {
        customerDtoList.add(_modelMapper.map(customer, CustomerDto.class));
    }

    return customerDtoList;
}



@CachePut(cacheNames = "customers", key = "#customerDto.id")
public CustomerDto addOrEditCustomer(CustomerDto customerDto) {
    if (customerDto.getId() == null || customerDto.getId() <= 0) {
       return addCustomer(customerDto);
    } else {
       return editCustomer(customerDto);
    }
}

private CustomerDto addCustomer(CustomerDto customerDto) {
    var customer = _modelMapper.map(customerDto, Customer.class);
    _customerRepository.save(customer);

    customerDto.setId(customer.getId());
    return customerDto;
}

private CustomerDto editCustomer(CustomerDto customerDto) {
    var customer = _customerRepository.findById(customerDto.getId()).orElse(null);
    if (customer == null)
        throw new DomainException("error.customer.notFound");

    _modelMapper.map(customerDto, customer);
    _customerRepository.save(customer);

    return customerDto;
}

@CacheEvict(value = "customers", key = "#customerId")
public void removeCustomer(Long customerId) {
    var customer = _customerRepository.findById(customerId).orElse(null);
    if (customer == null)
        throw new DomainException("error.customer.notFound");
    
    try
    {
        _customerRepository.delete(customer);
    }
    catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex)
    {
        throw new DomainException("error.public.dependent.entity");
    }
}
}

